# How do I execute code when a user switches back to my UWP app?

Tags: uwp

In Windows Phone and Windows 8.1, OnNavigatedTo would be invoked when a page became the visible page after navigation from any page. Now, it seems that this method is only called when switching between pages in the current app. How do I execute code when a user switches back to my app from another one (ie using the back button). I've tried the Application.Resuming event, but this is not fired either.

Comment: I hope this can help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt243287.aspx

Comment: Looks like Window.VisibilityChanged was what I needed for my mobile app. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Application.Resuming` event is only called if your app was actually suspended, which might not be the case. However, the application object has `OnActivated` plus a bunch of scenario-specific overrides; one of those is likely what you want.

Relying on `Window.VisibilityChanged` sounds iffy if you're targeting other device families than phone.